# Publish React Webapp

Tags: node.js, reactjs, build

i have already built a website on React and the build folder is online on the server where im working , but when i open from their website (my job website link for developers mode) it shows only the mainpage and even with wrong css(like the colours are there but the margin are not the ones i have in local). **If i click on any button or nav link it brings me nowhere**, just **not found** , but when i open it **in local** i can **access to all the pages** (more than 30 lol). I use Route.js for handle the paths and in local **works perfectly** , but **with the build version** of the app **that does not happen**. I tried to host it with the most famouse free servers online but it always do the same so i guess the problem is that something is missing in my project but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to deploy it using [heroku](https://heroku.com), If you have some problem, you can configure it with the next command: `heroku buildpacks:set mars/create-react-app`

Comment: Ok Heroku works , the problem is that it mess up my css with the margins but i didnt use absolute position just bootstrap grids so how is possible that the components does not have margins?

Comment: Can you explain me more? I mean, show me your code or some like that. CSS should works fine with React.

Comment: yes the Css works more than fine in local host the problem is where it goes there is like heroku or in general the build version of my app ignore margin css because the colors and all the position are perfect it just ignore margins